# Listing the contents of an archive non-recursively using `zipinfo`

Tags: zip, archive

Is there a flag that I can pass to the `zipinfo` command to list the contents of an archive non-recursively?

For example, if the target archive contains three directories, which in turn contain five empty directories each, I don't want the command to return fifteen elements, but only the three "**top**" or "**first-level**" directories.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the zip file format, things are not "recursive". In there, there's simply a list of files, whose names contain slashes (or more generally, path separators).

So, there's really 15 entries "flat" in your zip: the 15 "leaf" directories. The directories above are implied, since they are part of the path of these.

So, to find all top-level directories, you have to go through *all* entries, and extract the first path component, and then remove duplicates.

```bash
zipinfo -1 | sed -n 's;\([^/]*\)/.*;\1;p' | sort -u
```

Couple of things to note

- I don't know how zipinfo behaves when there's file names with line breaks in there
- if you're shifting around files between machines, where you need things like permissions, sparsity, ownership… [zip is not the right tool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/731609/difference-between-ar-tar-gzip-zip-and-when-should-i-decide-to-choose-which-o/731610#731610), as it can't do these things. Also, with tools like `mksquashfs`, you can just [make archives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/729368/make-the-smallest-image-of-system/729371#729371) that compress usually better, and can be directly mounted using `udisksctl loop-setup -f archive.squashfs` (and if necessary `udisksctl mount /dev/loopN` after) or just `mkdir mntdir; sudo mount -o loop archive.squashfs mountdir`, and then you can just use your usual file management (from `ls` to your favorite file browser) to inspect the contents at near-zero cost.

Comment: Very nice. I'll play around with it and see whether I can manage to also have it return the top files, and not just the top directories. Don't know if that's possible, though(?) I'm no a sed export. Thank you for your educative answer. I appreciate your time.

Comment: you can remove the `/` after the match group `\(…\)`

Comment: Oh, I see. Very cool, thanks so much.

Comment: `zipinfo` renders newlines as `^J` same as with literal `^J`. Use `bsdtar -tf file.zip` for a non-ambiguous output where newline is rendered as `\n` and backslash as `\\ `. `bsdtar -tf file.zip | LC_ALL=C sed -n 's;/.*;;p' | LC_ALL=C sort -u`